# Anytime: 随時 vs. 何時でも

Tags: usage, pragmatics

Is 随時{ずいじ} used to express **anytime** like いつでも?

Answer (score 5):

The words are actually quite different in their nuances: (and consequently not interchangeable)

- 随時 - as required  (e.g. 随時更新します - I will update as required (as things change))
- いつでも - at any time (e.g. いつでも来てください - Come whenever you like)

Comment: +1. 隋時 implies that there are many small requests/tasks which are served as they came. You cannot use 随時 for a one-time event.

Comment: I believe 随時 has two senses: 1) at any time 2) as needed.  My question was about the first sense, therefore l'électeur(http://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/4032/l%c3%a9lecteur) answer is the most appropriate.

Comment: @user1602 If you already knew the answer then why did you ask this question? 随時 does not mean at any time and cannot be used to reference a one time event as Naruto correctly pointed out. The consensus is clear that this answer is correct.

Comment: I was skeptical about the answer, and wanted a native Japanese speaker to confirm the JMDict translation. Obviously you do not trust l'électeur, so to confirm his answer I had to struggle with my limited Japanese to understand Goo 辞書 http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/srch/all/%E9%9A%8F%E6%99%82/m1u/ and it looks like one of the senses is 好きな時にいつでも, which very close to "anytime", and by the way, anytime does not imply one time - I don't know where this came from.

Comment: L'electeur provides many great answers, but on this particular occasion he is incorrect. I checked your link at it says "適宜" (as appropriate) and 定期的でないこと (irregularly). These terms are not interchangeable and they have different nuances. As I said, the consensus is clearly on this answer yet you seem very invested in the other answer.